# Selenium testing for duplicated text

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, duplicates

Is it possible in Selenium to check if a certain text appears more than once on a page (it doesn't matter how many times, just if it is more than once)?

I know that I can test for the text with

```
selenium.IsTextPresent(text)
```

But of course that returns true as soon as it finds the text once.  Is there a way to see if text exists multiple times on a page?

Comment: I would try, if LastIndexOf != IndexOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can operate on html source:

```
selenium.GetHtmlSource();
```

Then simple check for the index of the test and last index (as nabuchodonossor suggested in his comment):

```
selenium.GetHtmlSource().IndexOf(text) > -1 && selenium.GetHtmlSource().IndexOf(text) != selenium.GetHtmlSource().LastIndexOf(text)
```

You can also remove all html tags before checking indexes and leave the visible text only if you want to ignore comments, alt attributes, title attributes etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go is `sel.getElementCount(xpath)` or running a JS script using `sel.getEval()`. The advantage of these two methods over `sel.getHtmlSource()` is that you don't bring back the whole page html from the selenium server. The work is done on the server side and you save the bandwidth (and probably speed).